# Loading a string into a textview

Tags: c#, android, string, xamarin, textview

I need to load a string into a textview that is being displayed on a new page after a button click event. A java.lang.runtimeexception keeps getting thrown when i click the button. "java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException"

Here is that section of my code:

```
SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
        Button button1 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.story1);
        button1.Click += delegate {
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.next1);
            TextView textvtest = (TextView) FindViewById(Resource.Id.textView1);
            textvtest.Text = "test";
        };
```

Comment: Is there something I need to do to make a TextView ready to accept new text? I am new to app development. Thanks for the help

Comment: On button click, do you want the next activity, where the textview is present, to be shown? I mean, do you want the new activity to open?

Answer (score 2):

**From the first activity, in buttonClick :**

```
 button1.Click += delegate {
       var activity2 = new Intent (this, typeof(Activity2));
       activity2.PutExtra ("MyData", "test");
       StartActivity (activity2);
 };
```

**In the second activity, in `onCreate()` :**

```
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.next1);
        TextView textvtest = (TextView) FindViewById(Resource.Id.textView1);

        string text = Intent.GetStringExtra ("MyData") ?? "Data not available";
        textvtest.Text = text;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this matters, but other examples of setting textviews with C# include

```
(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

after

```
delegate
```

like

```
delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Answer (score 0):

your code was a little bit wrong, try this

```
SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
Button button1 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.story1);
button1.Click += delegate {
    SetContentView (Resource.Layout.next1);
    TextView textvtest = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
    textvtest.Text = "test";
};
```